# The (.htaccess) not working in php when and getting the error message on the server?

Tags: php

my (.htaccess) not working properly in the URL. I tried to go through the articles on online but not any article able to resolve this issue, please help me out with this issue which im facing with the (.htaccess).

I check the my code several times but not able to find the correct problem for this issue.

URL before (.htaccess) : localhost/worldsindia/shop/home.php?company=timefreefor

URL required : localhost/worldsindia/catalog/timefreefor

This is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $0.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    shop/home.php?company=$1 [NC,L]
```

URL required : localhost/worldsindia/catalog/timefreefor

when i try this with the above url im getting the error

REQUESTED URL NOT FOUND ON THE SERVER

Comment: please provide the solution..........